# Anitaromatic compounds: Why do they have lower stability?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

What is the cause for some compounds like cyclobutadiene to be antiaromatic?

I know they don't satisfy Huckle's rule but I don't understand why that leads to the decrease in stability of the compound. Whenever we analyse stability we look at steric hindrance, delocalization, etc. Delocalization of electrons does take place, then why does the stability decrease?